# how to SFTP in mule asking for KERBROS username and password

Tags: mule, mule-studio

how to stop  SFTP in mule asking for KERBROS username and password?
I have tried to implement thee previous solution by adding a class but it not worked for [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jb5dm.png)me can anyone suggest some thing thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Add `preferredAuthenticationMethods` attribute to SFTP connector with value `password` or `publickey` dependent on use.Please refer connection [documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/sftp-transport-reference#connector) for more details.

Comment: Is there any class or something we need to import beacuse after adding this i am getting error?